# using Case for NSUserDefaults in swift

Tags: swift

I have added this function to observe when an NSUserdefault has changed. The object in the NSUSerdefault will be Kids, Theatre, Arts for example. When the UserDefault is changed , I need to amend the PFQuery that goes to Parse, so I was thing of using the CASE statement to check. any ideas on how to do this ?

for example

```
switch defaults.stringForKey("EventType")
                    case setObject = "Kids"
    then the PFQuery
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since stringForKey returns an optional, just handle the enum:

```
switch defaults.stringForKey("EventType") {
case .Some("Kids"):     break
case .Some("Theater"):  break
case .Some("Arts"):     break
case .Some(let value):  break   // handle unknown EventType
case .None:             break   // handle EventType not set yet
}
```

Comment: Note that the last two cases are required because swift requires that switch cases be exhaustive.